# Using bootstrap icons with button_to "delete" in rails 3

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have this edit button:

```
<%= link_to edit_income_path(trans), class: "btn btn-default" do %>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
<% end %>
```

And I want a delete button to look the same with this icon: glyphicon glyphicon-trash, but I can't find the right syntax to make it work and look the same. My delete button now:

```
<%= button_to "delete", trans, :method=> :delete, :remote=> true %>
```

[image: This is what it looks like]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this...for example with `link`_to

```
<%= link_to (‘<i class=“fa fa-thumbs-up fa-lg”> </i>’).html_safe, vote_path(@image), :method=> :delete, :remote=> true%>
```

Comment: Used this solution. Thanks.

Comment: Good to hear this @misschoksondik... i will appreciate if you mark it as a  correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you are looking for??

```
<%= button_to trans, method: :delete, remote: true, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
<% end %>
```