# Including bootstrap glyphicon in Rails link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to include a bootstrap glyphicon in a Rails link. I thought:

```
<%= link_to "<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i>&nbsp; Sign up".html_safe, signup_path, :class => "button" %>
```

But apparently the way I include the glyphicon is incorrect as this on the server produces the error:

```
unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' ...=( link_to "<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i>" + ....
```

When I remove the  part the link works. How can I include the glyphicon in the link/button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do :

```
<%= link_to signup_path, class: "button" do %>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i>&nbsp; Sign up
<% end %>
```

I feel like its clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
<%= link_to "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-check'></i>&nbsp; Sign up".html_safe, signup_path, :class => "button" %>
```

So to use 'glyphicon glyphicon-check' instead of "glyphicon glyphicon-check".

Answer (score 0):

try this...for example with `link`_to.my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25309599/using-bootstrap-icons-with-button-to-delete-in-rails-3/25362680#25362680)

```
<%= link_to (‘<i class=“fa fa-thumbs-up fa-lg”> </i>’).html_safe, vote_path(@image), :method=> :delete, :remote=> true%>
```