# NoMethodError: undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/auctions/2/comments/9":String Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to build a comment system. and update the partials with ajax. Each comment belongs to an auction. Now I have this error since hours.. and cant figure it out:

> NoMethodError in Auctions#show
>
> > "undefined method `stringify_keys' for /auctions/2/comments/9":String

**Extracted Source (Around Line 12):**

```
   </p>

   <p>
     <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', auction_comment_path(comment.auction, comment), id: "#{comment.id}_delete", remote: true, method: :delete,  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
       <button class="btn btn-flat grey lighten-2 grey-text text-darken-2 waves-effect waves-light"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></button>
     <% end %>
     <%= link_to 'Edit Comment', edit_auction_comment_path(comment.auction, comment), remote: true do %>
```

**comments_controller.rb:**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :all_comments, only: [:index, :create, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_comments, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :html, :js

  # New Comment (Form)
  def new
    # find Auction related to new Comment
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
    @comment = Comment.new
    @auction.comments.build
  end

  def index
    # created in order to handle renders from this controller, which produce URL 'root/auctions/:id/comments'
    auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
    redirect_to auction
  end

  # Create Comment
  def create
    # find Auction related to new Comment
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
    @comment = @auction.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.save
    redirect_to auction_path(@auction), :notice => "Comment sent"
  end

  # Edit Comment
  def update
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.update_attributes(params[:body])
  end

  # Delete Comment
  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @auction = comment.auction
    @comment.destroy
    #redirect_to auction_path(@auction), :notice => "Comment deleted"
  end

  private
  def all_comments
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  def set_comments
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
    @comment = @auction.comments.find(params[:id])
  end

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

**views/auction/show.html.erb:**

```
    <h2>Questions & Answers</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col s12">
    <%= link_to new_auction_comment_path(@auction), remote: true do %>
        <button class="btn">New Question</button>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12" id="comment-form" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12" id="comments"><%= render @auction.comments %></div>
</div>
```

**views/comments/_comment.html.erb**

```
 <p>
  <strong>Commenter:</strong>
  <%= comment.user.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Comment:</strong>
  <%= comment.body %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', auction_comment_path(comment.auction, comment), id: "#{comment.id}_delete", remote: true, method: :delete,  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
    <button class="btn btn-flat grey lighten-2 grey-text text-darken-2 waves-effect waves-light"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></button>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit Comment', edit_auction_comment_path(comment.auction, comment), remote: true do %>
      <button>Edit</button>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

**views/comments/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for [@auction, @auction.comments.build], remote: true do |f| %>
      <%= f.input  :body %>
      <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25309599/using-bootstrap-icons-with-button-to-delete-in-rails-3

Comment: i accidentally pastet the wrong _comment.html.erb, but the solution from the link does not solve the problem.

Comment: Could you please show full error stack trace?

Comment: @Athar sorry, that indeed fixed the error. Thank you. Other error was in my destroy action: I missed a @